# How can you get high and low values across group using a group by in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization

Given the example table below, how can I retrieve the high and low range of the entire group using pure MySQL?  Is it possible?

Table:

```
string    low    high
=====================
abc         1      10
abc        11      20
def         2       5
def         3       6
```

Basic Query: *(Obviously this doesn't work, but what would?)*

```
SELECT * from `table` GROUP BY `string`;
```

I want to get here, via MySQL if possible:

```
string    low    high
=====================
abc         1      20
def         2       6
```

Comment: FYI your query does not work because it selects the `min` and `max` columns of a *single representative row* (selected by MySQL more or less "randomly"). Selecting fields directly in a group by statement results in unpredictable results when they are not directly part of the group by clause. you should always use an aggregate function. in your case `MIN()` and `MAX()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
SELECT string, MIN(low), MAX(high)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY string
```

Answer (score 4):

Although Benoit is close, technically this is the *correct* answer:

```
SELECT string, MIN(low) as low, MAX(high) as high
FROM table
GROUP BY string
```

Because it names the columns as per the requirements in the question